# Work file server to be accessed remotely

Tags: networking, vpn, network-shares, remote-access, windows-networking

Due to the Covid-19 situation, I have to sort out a work-from-home solution for the staff at my small company.  I have looked into how best to set this up, but I require the help of experts to give me some advice.

During my research, the solution which most people have found works for them in this kind of situation is using some sort of Remote Desktop or screen-sharing application.  This would suffice for document-focused work, but for the work that my company does, it may not provide the immediate feedback or response that the staff needs.  This is because most of our staff are digital artists who work mainly in motion-based projects -- they need to see realtime playback of their work, which relies much on timing of keyframes.  Remote Desktop just does not give the fast, realtime playback of a file actually loaded into the RAM of a machine, as the remote desktop "image" is being streamed over the net.  There are lots of artifacts and pops/pauses because of latency.

I would like to set up the file server at the office so that artists can directly access the files on the server from home.  Of course, security is of utmost importance.  Is there a way to create access logins for each artist so that they can gain access, securely, to the contents of the file server?  All they need is access to the data on the file server -- they have proper software to open these files on their own machines, at home.

I was also thinking about purchasing a hardware VPN switch, but I don't think I am experienced enough to set something like this up, especially given such a short time-frame.

So, in summary, my question is this: could you recommend a way to allow remote file access to a central file server, securely?  Hopefully, via software?

The file server itself is running Windows 10 Pro.

Thank-you for any insight.

Comment: You'd need a lot of bandwidth on the UPLINK for this to work, because if the files are big (most certainly, they are, them being video and/or photo and stuff), then if all of your staff members try to download at the same time, that's going to create a bottleneck. You can circumvent that by telling them to wait for their turn, though. Mostly, you can put all the files in the Public folder on your PC, create subfolders for each user, and allow permissions for each subfolder to a specific user. You'll have to leave your PC running all the time, though, and allow Remote Access in your... 1/2

Comment: 2/2 ... System parameters. That's not ideal, not by a long shot. You can also store those files on your OneDrive folder, if you have one, and if there's enough space there for all the files, and send invites to your staff, on an individually-permitted basis. This is going to take some time, because OneDrive will have to upload all the files to the Cloud. Which brings us back to, how good is your uplink?

Comment: 1/4 Ah, I think I wasn't clear with our workflow.  Normally, an artist would perform their motion work in software like After Effects or Maya, then render temporary video files to preview their work.  These preview video files would be rendered locally on their work machine.  Since these files are local, and the user is normally working at the office, playback of these files is no problem.

Comment: 2/4 When the user is working from home and, say, using a Remote Desktop software to control their work PC from home, the video files are still being rendered to their work's local PC, but the playback also needs to be streamed over the internet, which is very slow.

Comment: 3/4 This is why I would like the artists to merely be able to access their work data on the file system at the office through their personal PCs at home and load that data on their home local PCs.  The videos that are rendered from this workflow will be on their home local PC, so there is no worry about needing to stream the video playback over the internet.

Since the work data is always changing (client updates work data, artists themselves update work data), having them save and load their work from the office's file system is the best scenario.

Comment: 4/4 (Oops, unused)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying WireGuard.  It is free and open-source VPN software. It is peer-to-peer and works on Windows 10.  I have used it for a while now, but have not gotten around to setting it up on Winodws 10 server.  [Here is a guide.](https://www.henrychang.ca/how-to-setup-wireguard-vpn-server-on-windows/)
The router at your office would need ports opened on it to allow incoming connections to the server.
Even with good broadband speeds, opening and editing large video files remotely might not work...and things might slow down or break if too many people try to connect simultaneously, but it would be worth a try.

Comment: Thank-you, I will check out WireGuard.  I just looked at it quickly and it might do what we need it to.

It seems, though, that the link to the guide you posted is not working?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In Remote Desktop Protocol, the "actual work" is done on the server (let's call it that), and is just displayed on the remote user's PC screen, so yes, what you see as a remote user is a series of snapshots (bitmaps), and yes, it does lag and isn't ideal to do any kind of video watching, let alone editing or that sort of thing. What I meant to say was, if the file your staff members must work on is hosted on the PC running Windows 10 you mentioned, then your employees will have to download them from your PC onto theirs. So you must have a stong uplink, and they, a strong downlink. Right?

Comment: The artists, for the most part, are creating their own materials, created in each software package, for their motion art.  They are not using large video files to edit.  Things like vector graphics, particle effects, smoke, etc. are created within After Effects or Maya, so there are no big video files for them to manipulate.  When they have to check their work, they must output a video, which, even if small, needs realtime playback to be properly checked.  So, data-wise, a fast connection is ideal, but not totally necessary.  But for motion check, they need realtime feedback.

Comment: In addition to a VPN, you might want to look into setting up a cloud-based workflow.  Many business are now doing this in place of any work files-server. It's cheap, fast, secure, and provides for easy file sharing.  For $100 / year, this subscription from Microsoft is hard to beat.  https://products.office.com/en-us/onedrive/compare-onedrive-plans?activetab=tab:primaryr1